# Ubuntu wifi makes ipad wifi very slow

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, ipad

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Since one week, the wifi of the ipad is very slow when the wifi of the ubuntu is active.

If I use a Ethernet cable everything is ok.

Both are working with DHCP

Any idea?